# CSS Resize an image with clip-path to fit parent container

Tags: css, reactjs, styled-components

I'm creating a page with cards for each employee.  In each card there will be an employee photo to the left, and personalia to the right.  I've gotten a clip path from our UX designer to shape the image with.  But when using the clip path, I can't figure out how to get the image to resize automatically to the parent div.  As such, I'm not able to do any resizing of the card with media queries etc.

I assume I either have to get the clip path to automatically resize to fit the image, or to get the whole EmployeePhoto component to automatically resize to fit the parent div.  But I haven't found a solution for either so far.

Any idea how I can get the image and clip path to resize automatically?  Preferably a CSS only solution.

Here's a code sandbox to show my problem: https://codesandbox.io/s/elated-lalande-k1csv

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I found a solution.  Ish...

I was able to convert the coordinates in the clip path from absolute to relative using this webpage: https://yoksel.github.io/relative-clip-path/

I could furthermore include the relative clip path as a "definition" in the start of the page.

```
<svg style={{ height:0, width:0, display: 'inherit' }}>
  <clipPath id="drop-clip-path" clipPathUnits="objectBoundingBox">
    <path d="M0.508,1 C0.226,1,-0.005,0.774,0,0.492 C0.004,0.218,0.229,0,0.503,0 H1 V0.497 C1,0.77,0.782,0.995,0.508,1" />
  </clipPath>
</svg>
```

I could then use the clip path in the styling of the EmployeePhoto component.

```
const EmployeePhoto = styled.img`
  margin-right: 1rem;
  height: 100%;
  clip-path: url(#drop-clip-path);
`;
```

I've created a new sandbox here: https://codesandbox.io/s/elegant-nash-48st7?file=/src/App.js

Granted, this is probably hacky as h*ll. But as long as it works and the debug console isn't screaming profanities against me, I'm satisfied.

If you have a better approach on this, I would be glad to hear it.